# Combine two queries into one without using temp tables

Tags: sql

I want to substact `mincall` from `callzero`. I am getting `mincall` from the first query and `callzero` from the second. How can I combine these queries so I don't have to use temp tables?

```
select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(CALENDAR))) as mincal 
from STATS
group by clientid
```

And :

```
select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(CALENDAR))) as callzero, CLIENTID from STATS
where calls = 0
and CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), CALENDAR)) < getdate()-2
group by clientid
```

**UPDATE**

I have these queries merged as follows -

```
select b.CLIENTID from
(
    select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(CALENDAR))) as mincal
    from STATS
    group by CLIENTID
) a,
(
    select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(CALENDAR))) as callzero, CLIENTID
    from STATS
    where calls = 0 and CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), CALENDAR)) < getdate()-2
    group by clientid
) b
group by clientid
```

But I still cannot subtract `mincall` from `callzero` without they being in the group by clause.

**UPDATE 2**

The calendar field is in this format `yyyymmdd`. For example, `20170922`.

Comment: Depending on your desired output, you're going to probably be looking at a `JOIN` statement or a `UNION` statement.   It would help us to see the current separate outputs .. and an example of your desired "single" output.

Comment: What **is** `CALENDAR` ? why are these conversions needed?

Comment: @wildplasser I have updated my question.

Comment: Is there any sane reason not to use a date (or datetime or timestamp) type for the CALENDAR column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your queries can be simplified in a single, simple statement by using *conditional aggregation*.

Consider :

```
SELECT  
    clientid, 
    MIN(calendar) as mincal 
    MIN(CASE WHEN calls = 0 AND calendar < getdate()-2 THEN calendar END) as callzero,
    DATEDIFF(
        DAY,
        MIN(CASE WHEN calls = 0 AND calendar < getdate()-2 THEN calendar END),
        MIN(calendar)
    ) as date_interval 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        clientid, 
        CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), calendar)) calendar
    FROM STATS
)
GROUP BY clientid
```

Notes :

- I understand that the dates in `CALENDAR` are stored as integers, hence the double conversion. To limit the number of conversions, I moved it to a subquery.
- In the third column, only rows having `calls = 0` and `calendar` within the last two days are taken into account ; for other rows, the `CASE` statement returns `NULL`, which is basically ignored by the `MIN` aggregate function.
- in sql-server, [`DATE_DIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to substract dates (here, the query returns the number of days between the two computed dates)

Comment: I have updated my question with specifics on the `calendar` field.

Comment: SQL Server. The reason I didn't use `case` is because I don't just need `calls = 0`. I need `calls = 0 ignoring the two most recent days` as outlined in this statement - `CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), CALENDAR)) < getdate()-2`

Comment: OK, let me check

Comment: what is the datatype of `CALENDAR` ?